# What a strange error in JS formatting of a new object?

Tags: javascript

My javascript code that produces a syntax error:

```
var x =
{
  a: 123
};
```

The same code without an error:

```
var x = {
  a: 123
};
```

What the heck?

Comment: Your code doesn't produce **any** SyntaxError, the Automatic Semicolon Insertion does **not** affect an `AssignmentExpression`, check [this example](http://jsbin.com/ukimi/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript adds implicit ";" at the end of lines sometimes, I suppose this is what happens, and results in

```
var x = ;
```

Comment: For this reason, it's recommended to always use the second form.

Comment: it is one of the gotchas in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154215/what-are-the-most-common-causes-of-errors-in-javascript-and-how-to-fix-them/3154285#3154285

Comment: That's not true. The variable statement is affected by the *Automatic Semicolon Insertion*, but the example that the OP posts, will *not cause any syntax error*, the `AssignmentExpression` will be evaluated *without problems*, check this question for the specific [rules of ASI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/) and [this example](http://jsbin.com/ukimi/edit).

Comment: I was also surprised by the error the OP had, so what could be the problem ? Thank you CMS for the correction.